# Route based code splitting with react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, code-splitting

Looking at the React doc, I implemented the [route-based code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) part in my application.

But I get an error:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

It seems it's coming from Redux that doesn't support function passed as components arguments and crashes when we import components with the `lazy()` function just like I do in my code:

```
const Login = lazy(() => import("../../containers/Login/Login"))
```

Do you have any workaround solution? I found [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) but that's not exactly what I want to implement.

Comment: Are you exporting the `Login` component with `export default ...`?

Comment: Yes I am. `export default withStyles(styles)(component)`